# Como cambiar los valores de filas y columnas a 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla que estoy filtrando por sitio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que los valores de todas las columnas de las filas donde sale null el sitio cambien a 0, intente con un:

```
case when "Site" is null then week_proj... = '0'
```

pero no me hace los cambios de las columnas ni agrega unas con los cambios ):

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis correcta sería:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN site IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE week_proj END AS week_proj
FROM ...
```

Más info:

- [PostgreSQL CASE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/)

Comment: muchas gracias si lo cambio, una pregunta hay forma de cambiar la columna inicial de week_proj por la del case, hacer como un update para que se esten actualizando los datos?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer un `UPDATE` para que los datos sean persistidos en la base de datos. Ya que estamos, te recomiendo realizar el [tour]